# How to get the full data list from auto complete function on textbox?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, vb.net, autocomplete, textbox

I have used autocomplete function on textbox,on typing any letter it populates the data list,but i want to populate the total data list on click on the textbox without typing any letter inside the textbox.
Here is the code i have used:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {

    $("#<%=Searchtxt.ClientID %>").autocomplete({
        source: function (request, response) {
            $.ajax({
                url: '<%=ResolveUrl("~/WebService.asmx/Get") %>',
                data: "{ 'prefix': '" + request.term + "'}",
                dataType: "json",
                type: "POST",
                scroll: true,
                scrollHeight: 180,
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                success: function (data) {
                    response($.map(data.d, function (item) {
                        return {
                            label: item.split('-')[0],
                            val: item.split('-')[1]
                        }
                    }))
                },
                error: function (response) {
                    alert(response.responseText);
                },
                failure: function (response) {
                    alert(response.responseText);
                }
            });
        },
        select: function (e, i) {
            $("#<%=bHdn.ClientID %>").val(i.item.val);
        },
        minLength: 1
    });
});

 </script>
```

Comment: here is a link which can help you http://jqueryui.com/resources/demos/autocomplete/combobox.html

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

[Reference](http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#remote-jsonp)

Remove

```
data: "{ 'prefix': '" + request.term + "'}",
```

and add instead of above

```
data: { 'prefix': request.term },
```